# I am trying to change the background image as soon as the respective option is selected from the select drop down list. but this is not happening

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function bgimg() {
  var ch = document.getElementById("country").value;
  if (ch == "None") {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.background = "black";
  } else if (ch == "India") {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5770.jpg')";
  } else if (ch == "USA") {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage = "url('Usa.jpghttps://wallpaperaccess.com/full/52904.jpg')";
  } else if (ch == "Japan") {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/6512.jpg')";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1833702.jpg')";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center" style="font-family: umpush;">WELCOME TO INTERACTIVITY</h1>
<div id="bgi"></div>
<select id="country" onchange="Javascipt: bgimg()">
  <option value="None">None</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
</select>
```

/* I am trying to change the background image as soon as the respective option is selected from the select drop down list. but this is not happening.
OUTPUT: No background is being shown after choosing the options */

Comment: take a second look at the `onchange` attribute. And at the URL of the USA image.

Comment: @f1sh i considered your advice and corrected the typos, still nothing is happening.

Comment: @sagar your cleaning brings this error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: bgimg is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 19,
  "colno": 67
}

Comment: I improved a pending edit by another user and I didn't noticed that he put the js code in css field. The issue is already fixed

Comment: fyi, your code is working fine and the only thing you need to do is, give a width and height to `div#bgi` and clear the USA problem mentioned by f1sh

Comment: @SagarV Thanks bro it works in the stackoverflow ide but not on mine. 
Can you tell me the significance of calling the bgimg() function in the script only please?

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript code was put into the css textarea. And there were some typos in your code ("Javascipt" and a wrong image url).

Also he backgrounds were set on an empty div without any styling, which results in not seeing them. I have added a height and width on it so that you can at least see the backgrounds. Furthermore I called the function at the start so that it will set the background for the initial value (which is "None" so the background becomes black)

```js
function bgimg() {
  var ch = document.getElementById("country").value;
  if (ch == "None") {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundColor = "black";
  } else if (ch == "India") {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5770.jpg')";
  } else if (ch == "USA") {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/52904.jpg')";
  } else if (ch == "Japan") {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/6512.jpg')";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1833702.jpg')";
  }
}

bgimg();
```

```css
#bgi {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center" style="font-family: umpush;">WELCOME TO INTERACTIVITY</h1>
<div id="bgi"></div>
<select id="country" onchange="Javascript: bgimg()">
  <option value="None">None</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The issue is caused by a typo and the question already have 2 close votes. You could've flagged it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an event listener for change on Javascript if you want. Also, do not forget to give the #bgi div a width and height on CSS otherwise it won't show.

```
    
<h1 align="center" style="font-family: umpush;">WELCOME TO INTERACTIVITY</h1>
    <div id="bgi"></div>
    <select id="country">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>    
    </select> 


const select = document.querySelector("#country");

select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const ch = document.getElementById("country").value;
  
  console.log(ch);
  
  if(ch=="None") {document.getElementById("bgi").style.background="black";}
  else if(ch=="India") {document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage="url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5770.jpg')";}
  else if(ch=="USA") {document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage="url('Usa.jpghttps://wallpaperaccess.com/full/52904.jpg')";}
  else if(ch=="Japan") {document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage="url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/6512.jpg')";}
  else {document.getElementById("bgi").style.backgroundImage="url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1833702.jpg')";}

});
```